# How to embed a tooltip icon in a Select (material-ui)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI tooltip component and I am trying to align my tooltip to the right of my dropdown--right next to the down arrow carrot shown like in the image below,

[image]

But the way I have it now, the tooltip is added below the select in a funky way.

---

```
  <FormControl label='Identifier Type' style={{ width: '100%' }}>
    <Select
      ...
    />
      <Tooltip disableHoverListener onClose={handleTooltipClose} open={open} placement='right' title='Helper....'>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleTooltipOpen}>
          <Icon
            size="small"
            accessibleText='Delete Row'
            name='help'
            style={{ color: '4c505b' }}
          />
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  </FormField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) of `Select`, it seems not possible to append a helper icon to the component as of now (v5.14.11). However, with styling, you can make it look like it belongs :) You can use MUI's `makeStyles`. For simplicity, I did that with inline-styling. Notice that I added `Box` from MUI and removed the `Button`:

```
<FormControl variant="standard" label="Identifier Type" >
    <Box style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "flex-end"}}>
        <InputLabel id="color">Color</InputLabel>
        <Select
            value=""
            label="Color"
            labelId="color"
            style={{ width: '200px' }}
        >
            <MenuItem value="1">Green</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="2">Orange</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="3">Red</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        <Tooltip disableHoverListener title="helper.." placement="right" >
            <HelpCenterIcon 
                fontSize="small"
                name="help"
                style={{ color: "#757575", padding: "5px 10px", borderBottom: "1px solid #949494", }}
            />
        </Tooltip>
    </Box>
</FormControl>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: result]

Let me know if you want the `makeStyles` solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Amrovic's answer broke some styling in my case on mobile, but was able to achieve similar result with Select component's renderValue prop:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel id={id}>{label}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId={id}
    id={id}
    name={id}
    value={values[id]}
    label={label}
    onChange={onChange}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    renderValue={(value: string) => (
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
        {value}
        {tooltipText && <Tooltip content={tooltipText} />}
      </Box>
    )}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
        {option}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```